# PHP and XML fusion, correctly encoding special characters

Tags: php, xml, regex

I've got a database that outputs a great deal of information.
I'm currently building a PHP application to build this database into an XML format for another application to read.

I'm a little stuck with special characters.
In the database, some characters are printing strangely:

Ø becomes Ã˜
° becomes Â°

I'm using fwrite() to write the XML file in the PHP and I think the error resides there somehow.

I need a way to overcome this, perhaps by detecting where an occurrance of these characters occur and replacing them appropriately.

I'm using PHP and I'm not sure how to replace these characters on an individual basis, and more importantly, I'm not sure what to replace them with!

Can someone help?

Comment: Which charset do you use for xml and for tables. If they have same, unwanted replacement must not happen.

Comment: the XML is an apple plist file so it uses UTF-8

Comment: +1, exactly yes as Daniel said, and chars are somehow converted to ASCII, instead if UTF-8.

Comment: And what about database table? Do they also use UTF-8

Comment: At the moment, the string is echoing from the PHP with the correct symbols - Ø and °. If I try and use utf8_encode, the appear much like I've printed above.

Comment: The database table uses latin1_swedish_ci (which was set up as standard on the system I'm using). They are also stored as above (incorrectly)

Comment: I'm using fwrite() to write the XML file in the PHP and I think the error resides there somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ø` becomes `Ã˜`, `°` becomes `Â°`

Looks like that UTF-8 encoded characters are passed to some display device and it's told the display device that those are ISO-8859-X or Windows-125X encoded characters.

Tell the display device that this is indeed UTF-8 (which is by default the standard encoding for XML).

Comment: As mentioned, it's outputting to an apple plist file which, as it's top line shows: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and I'm also using `fwrite($fh, utf8_encode($output));` to write the file. I'm not sure how I'd be able to force UTF-8 more than this.

Comment: Yes it's outputting that. But that what *displays* the output is so sure it's not UTF-8 but something else. **Tell** the output device that it's UTF-8. Otherwise don't expect that the output device is clever enough to guess what you want to display and how.

Comment: I have `Â°` in my database, `°` on my screen when I echo from the PHP, `Â°` in the XML once it's been written to a file with `fwrite($fh, utf8_encode($output));`, `Â°` when the XML is displayed in X-Code, and finally `Â°` on my app, even after I use `[NSString stringWithUTF8String]` to convert it. I've even tried casting the string as a UTF8 String via the string format specifier `%s`

Comment: Well, whatever you do, I'm sure you have no clue about the actual encoding otherwise you would be more specific here. As the database is the source, it looks misleading that you say you have `Â°` in your database. If you see that, what is the encoding of what you see? I mean under which encoding is the display device showing you that what you think is in your database? Can you display a binary dump of that data from the database as well? If so, share it. When you write to the XML file, don't UTF-8 encode. I have the feeling if you stop doing that, the file will be okay.

Comment: I really dont understand character encoding or anything. I'm just determined to get this issue fixed because I need the `Ø` and the `°` in my app! My database is run in phpMyAdmin and it says the encoding is `latin1_swedish_ci`

Comment: Thats the collation (not encoding), but I assume your encoding is `latin1` then. So you've stored UTF-8 data as Latin-1 into the database. You should fix the data inside the database (treat the strings as binary and utf8_decode them, store the binary result back) and you should be fine then. To prevent similar in the future, convert the encoding to UTF-8, and save as UTF-8 to your database and access the database in UTF-8 mode. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset.html

Comment: Ah, this has fixed the issue, it places the symbols correctly into the xml, now I have another issue though - the plist is 'corrupt' because it doesn't like the extra characters. I must escape them somehow...

Comment: As long as it's UTF-8 those characters are valid XML. Who states the XML is "corrupt"?

Comment: X-Code. I've fixed it now. Thanks for all your help. Felt a bit lost in a field of knowledge I know nothing about - encoding/collation/utf8! I utf8_decode in php and then straight after ran utf8_encode and it works. Strange that, but I'm now getting the correct display where I need it!

Comment: If you fixed it and it works for your (even fragile), be lucky. Because to really fix these encoding problems, you need to be pretty straight and actually know what you do if you want to be on the safe side. So good luck and finally something did work for you ;)